# Get last part of URL

Tags: c++, url

How would I get the last part of a URL?
Say the variable `url` is `https://somewhere.com/stuff/hello`.
How would I get `hello` from this?

Comment: `"hello"` seems to be everything after the last `'/'`.

Comment: It's not very clear, is this a question about string operations? About the format of URLs? As usual its easier to answer if you explain why you are stuck.

Comment: There are multiple ways. 1) You can reverse the string and read the characters until u see first '/' character. 2) You can use regex 3) Just start the loop from back and stop when you see '/' character. 4) U can use substr with rfind. This seems to be straight-forward. Not sure where u r stuck

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
 
    const std::string url("https://somewhere.com/stuff/hello");
    const std::size_t indexLastSeparator = url.find_last_of("/");
    if (indexLastSeparator != std::string::npos)
    {
        const std::string lastPartUrl = url.substr(indexLastSeparator+1); // +1 to not keep /
        std::cout << lastPartUrl << '\n'; // print "hello"
    }
}
```

With find_last_of() and substr()

references :

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: `szUrl` and `szHello`? Reverse polish notation is bad enough, inappropriately applied its even worse.

Comment: @john I modified.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rfind` and `substr`

Maybe with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string url{"https://somewhere.com/stuff/hello"};

    std::cout << url.substr(url.rfind('/')+1);

    return 0;
}
```

But only, if you have a / in front of the last part